# C# XmlReader: preserve nbsp entity when parsing XHTML

Tags: c#, xml, xhtml, xmlreader

I need to parse an (almost) arbitrary XML string, which is obtained from XHTML. For example, `<root>test default values &amp;&nbsp;&lt;&gt;</root>`. To solve the issue with XHTML entities I configure the `XmlReader` the following way:

```
    private XmlParserContext GetXhtmlParserContext()
    {
        var nameTable = new NameTable();
        var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
        var context = new XmlParserContext(nameTable, namespaceManager, null, XmlSpace.Preserve)
        {
            DocTypeName = XhtmlDocTypeName,
            PublicId = XhtmlPublicId,
            SystemId = XhtmlSystemId
        };

        return context;
    }

    private XmlReaderSettings GetXhtmlReaderSettings()
    {
        return new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
            ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD,
            XmlResolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver(XmlKnownDtds.All)
        };
    }
```

And then I use it the following way:

```
    public XmlNode DeserializeXhtml(string xhtmlContent)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlNode));
        XmlParserContext context = GetXhtmlParserContext();
        XmlReaderSettings settings = GetXhtmlReaderSettings();
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xhtmlContent))
        {
            using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings, context))
            {
                return (XmlNode)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }
```

It works perfectly fine, except for one issue: for some reason it does convert an `&nbsp;` entity to an actual whitespace when reading from a string. So, I get an `XmlNode` which contains `test default values &amp; &lt;&gt;` in InnerXml property. I really need to preserve the entity if at all possible. Are there any ways to do it?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I assume it may not be the best way of getting `XmlNode` from a string, but it's not my code and I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that's not just the behaviour of InnerXml, that it just doesn't serialize the U+00A0 character as an entity reference, but does (because it has to, to preserve the integrity of the XML) serialize the `&`, `<`, and `>` characters as named entity references? i.e. Is your deserialization correct, and you just need to serialize the DOM document back to XML differently?

Comment: @Alohci well, no, I'm not sure it's not a standard behaviour of InnerXml which cannot be changed. It could be, but I was wondering if it could be configured.
Generating of HTML, which gets converted to XML in JS is the responsibility of a WYSIWYG editor called Redactor. It automatically puts in the nbsp entity in case it's a trailing space (for example). So, I cant change the way of producing the markup, only its deserialization. Do you have any ideas how to deserialize XML from a string, keeping in mind that I'll have not only pure XML entities, but also XHTML entities? Thanks